# read directory from serial port java

Tags: java, file-io, serial-port

I am using a barcode scanner unitech HT630.

I already know how to send/receive data from the serial port, but now I want to display list of files from the serial port.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The serial port is just a mean of physical communication of bytes. To do high level stuff, like listing files, you need to know the application protocol. Check if you have a protocol spec. supplied with the device.

Comment: What is attached to the serial port that you want to read files and directories from?